# Glide doesn't show image in first fragment "automatically"

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-glide, android-viewpager2

In my application I can create albums with photos, store them on Firebase and view them.

Well, in order to browse these albums I decided to create something like viewing screenshots of an app/game in the Play Store in full screen.
I created `Activity` and added `ViewPager2` to this `Activity`, then I created `Fragment` and `Adapter` to show my images and everything seems to work but there are some problems with Glide.

First I tried to use this code to load photos:
`Glide.with(MediaViewerFragment.this).load(imageUrl).into(image);` but the pictures were not showing.

On stackoverflow I found a solution - it was to add a listener to the method and instead of `into(View)` use `submit()` So I wrote such a listener:

```java
RequestListener<Drawable> listener = new RequestListener<>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                errorLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorReasonText.setText(e.getMessage());
                loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Test", "Glide: Cannot load image: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                image.setImageDrawable(resource);
                image.invalidate();
                loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Test", "Glide: Image loaded");
                return false;
            }
        };

        Glide.with(MediaFragment.this).load(imageUrl).addListener(listener).submit();
```

but:

- When I open the album the photo in the first Fragment does not appear immediately after loading, the image "loads into imageview" only when I touch the ViewPager2 with my finger or scroll to the next Fragment and return to the first one.
- ProgressBar does not disappear on first fragment

and I don't know why this is happening. I think that this happens because maybe the first Glide Listener is begin replaced by other listeners in others fragments with images?

As you can see, in `OnResourceReady` I have `Log.d("Test", "Glide: Image loaded");` but it doesn't appear to me in LogCat (on first fragment, when i swipe to others fragment then everything works fine!). But when I put `Log.d("Test", "Glide: Image loaded");` on top so it will look like this:

```java
@Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                Log.d("Test", "Glide: Image loaded");
                image.setImageDrawable(resource);
                image.invalidate();
                loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
```

then:

- When I open the album then immediately in logcat I get my message that the photo has been uploaded but unfortunately, I still can't see it and ProgressBar doesn't disappear.
- I still need to swipe to next fragment and go back to previous to see that image.

[Video describing the problem](https://streamable.com/rj3wez) - you can see that I have to touch the screen for the photo to load which is weird and shouldn't happen

MediaViewerFragment.java

```java
public class MediaViewerFragment extends Fragment {
    View mRootView;

    private ImageView image;
    private LinearLayout errorLinear, loadingLinear;
    private MaterialTextView errorReasonText;

    private String imageUrl;

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        context = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    public MediaViewerFragment(Context context, String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.context = context;
        Log.d("Teest", "MediaFragment - Image to load: " + imageUrl);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_media, container, false);
        return mRootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        initView();
        setup();
    }

    private void initView() {
        image = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        errorLinear = (LinearLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.error_linear);
        errorReasonText = (MaterialTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.error_reason_text);
        loadingLinear = mRootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_progress_bar);
    }

    private void setup() {
        Log.d("Test", "Preparing to load image: " + imageUrl);

        RequestListener<Drawable> listener = new RequestListener<>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                errorLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorReasonText.setText(e.getMessage());
                loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Test", "Glide: Cannot load image: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                image.setImageDrawable(resource);
                image.invalidate();
                loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Test", "Glide: Image loaded");
                return false;
            }
        };

        Glide.with(MediaViewerFragment.this)load(imageUrl).addListener(listener).submit();
    }
}
```

ViewPager Adapter:

```java
public class MediaViewerViewPager extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private List<AlbumImage> imagesUrls;

    private Context context;


    public MediaViewerViewPager(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle, Context context, List<AlbumImage> imagesUrls) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        this.imagesUrls = imagesUrls;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return new MediaFragment(context, imagesUrls.get(position).getImageUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesUrls.size();
    }
}
```

Activity where my ViewPager2 is:

```java
public class MediaViewerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager2 imagesViewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_viewer);

        initView();
        setup();
    }

    private void initView() {
        imagesViewpager = (ViewPager2) findViewById(R.id.images_viewpager);
    }

    private void setup() {
        MediaViewerViewPager adapter = new MediaViewerViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle(), MediaViewerActivity.this, new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("albumImages"), new TypeToken<List<AlbumImage>>() {}.getType()));
        imagesViewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

---

#### Fixed

After adding the `placeholder` and `error` methods to the code, everything works.
Correct code looks like this now:

```
Glide.with(image)
                .load(getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.transparent_background)
                .error(R.drawable.transparent_background)
                .addListener(new RequestListener<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        errorLinear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        errorReasonText.setText(e.getMessage());

                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Drawable resource, Object model, Target<Drawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        loadingLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(image);
```

Comment: Since the fragment is inside a ViewPager, and you are using the Fragment constructor to initialize the arguments, that could be the issue. Instead of sending arguments through the constructor of a fragment, use Bundle arguments, which are going to be available the next time the fragment is recreated. Take a look at this example https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment `DetailsFragment.newInstance(..)`

Comment: @WilsonCastiblanco
Thanks for response. 
I did what is in the Documentation, but I get the same result like with ```new DetailsFragment(...)```
Here is the video describing how the problem works - You can see that Image shows only when I touch the fragment or I started scrolling to next activity.
https://streamable.com/rj3wez

Comment: have you tried to loading by using `Glide.with(View)` and set `placeholder` image and `error` image. it might let you know what is happening!

Comment: @VishalBeep Strange but adding `placeholder` and `error` to the code fixed the problem - photos now load correctly. I don't know how it works that these two methods fix this problem. How can I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Added answer now you can mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to loading by using

```
Glide.with(View)
```

and set `placeholder` image and `error` image. it might let you know what is happening!

something like this -

```
 Glide.with(view)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .error(R.drawable.someErrorImage)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.somePlaceHolderImage)
       .into(view);
```